# Reducing time and memory used in loop calculation when locating earthquakes

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension, numpy-ndarray, grid-search

I'm trying to locate tremor, which is a type of earthquake with smaller amplitude. I use grid search, which is a method that finds the coordinate where 'the difference between theoretical value and observed value of differential time in seismic wave arrival' becomes minimum.

The code I made is as follows. First I defined two functions that calculate distance between earthquake source and each point on grid, and that calculate travel time of seismic waves using obspy.

```
def distance(a,i):
    return math.sqrt(((ste[a].stats.sac.stla-la[i])**2)+((ste[a].stats.sac.stlo-lo[i])**2))

def traveltime(a):
    return model.get_travel_times(source_depth_in_km=35, distance_in_degree=a, phase_list=["S"], receiver_depth_in_km=0)[0].time
```

Then I conducted grid search using following codes.

```
di=[(la[i],lo[i],distance(a,i), distance(b,i)) for i in range(len(lo))
    for a in range(len(ste))
    for b in range(len(ste)) if a<b]

didf=pd.DataFrame(di)

latot=didf[0]
lotot=didf[1]
dia=didf[2]
dib=didf[3]
```

```
tt=[]
for i in range(len(di)):
    try:
        tt.append((latot[i],lotot[i],traveltime(dia[i])-traveltime(dib[i])))
    except IndexError:
        continue

ttdf=pd.DataFrame(tt)
```

```
final=[(win[j],ttdf[0][i],ttdf[1][i],(ttdf[2][i]-shift[j])**2) for i in range(len(ttdf))
      for j in range(len(ccdf))]
```

where la and lo are the list of latitude and longitude coordinates with 0.01 degree interval, and ste is the list of the east components seismogram of each station. I have to get the list 'final' to proceed to the next step.

However, the problem is that it takes too much time to calculate three segments of codes written above. Moreover, the result I get after tens of hours of calculation is 'out of memory' error message. Is there any solution that can reduce both time and memory?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your dataset, it's a little difficult to debug, but here are a few suggestions for you.

```
for i in range(len(di)):
    try:
        tt.append((latot[i],lotot[i],traveltime(dia[i])-traveltime(dib[i])))
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

•  Given the size of these lists, I think that the Garbage Collector might be slowing down this for loop; you might consider turning it off for the duration of the loop (gc.disable()).

•  In theory, the Append statement shouldn't be the source of your performance problems, since it over-allocates:

```
/* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 */
new_allocated = (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

but you already know the size of the array, so you might consider using numpy.zeroes() to fill the list before the for-loop, and use the index to directly address each element.  Alternatively, you could just use list comprehensions, as you did earlier, and avoid the problem altogether.

• I see that you've tagged the question with python-3.x, so range() shouldn't be an issue like it was in 2.x (otherwise you would want to consider using xrange()).

If you update your question with more details, I could probably provide a more detailed answer...hope this helps.